# Devise with 2 resources to login return name for one resource and object for another

Tags: ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Using devise in an app that had login only for `users`, now I added login for `companies` too.
Got into an issue where devise is showing user name instead of an object:

```
<%= current_user %> displays: John Deer
<%= current_company %> displays: #<Company:0x7f045be0b800>
```

The app I am working on was started by someone else and can't say if some devise method have been rewritten or not.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to define a `to_s` method for your Company model

```
class Company
  def to_s
    self.name
  end
end
```

Where `self.name` is whatever you want to display instead.

Comment: Nice! Thank you, there was a method in User model called to_s that returned name when I needed the object, all good now.

Comment: Seems like i was misunderstanding your question, i didn't thought you actually wanted to display the object address, but glad you could figure it out anyway :)